# require-css: including a css file who's path has "css" in it (ex: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css)

Tags: requirejs

My require.js config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        css: "../libs/require-css/css",
    },
    map: {
        "*": {
            less: "../libs/require-less/less",
            css: "../libs/require-css/css"
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying to include a css file that has "css" in dir name

```
require([
    "css!bootstrap/../css/bootstrap"
], function(
) {
```

Gets interpreted as  `libs/require-css/css/bootstrap.css` because `css` is in the directory name. How would I get require to treat `css` in the path a literal

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to change the path you'd like to use.

Instead of:

```
paths: {
   css: "../libs/require-css/css",
},
```

use this

```
paths: {
   require-css: "../libs/require-css/css",
},
```

Then reference it as

```
require([
    "require-css!bootstrap/../css/bootstrap"
], function(
) {
```

The paths just work as a shortcut or alias to the longer location of the file so you can use any value you like for it.

Answer (score 0):

Any short module name in paths should not exist in a file path.

For example, if `path : {css: 'path/to/require/css'},`
and

```
require(['css!css/style.css'],  function () {});
```

'css' string in style.css's file path will be replaced with the module css's path.
so that equals to

```
require(['css!path/to/require/css/style.css'],  function () {});
```

To prevent this problem, you can replace css module name with 'require-css' like Denis did

```
path : {require-css: 'path/to/require/css'};
require(['require-css!css/style.css'],  function () {});
```

or replace css directory name 'css' with 'style'

```
path : {css: 'path/to/require/css'};
require(['css!style/style.css'],  function () {});
```